# Canvas change width depending on percentage complete

Tags: node.js, canvas, discord.js

I have an xp system and I have the percentage of how far someone is to leveling up, and I created a rectangle. but I don't know how to change the width depending on the percentage...
I have the percentage easily, but I need a way to code that percentage 0 = start point of 259, and 100 percent is 630

```js
    const rectX = 259;
    const rectY = 182;
    const rectWidth = 630;
    const rectHeight = 38;
    const cornerRadius = 20;

    ctx.lineJoin = 'round';
    ctx.lineWidth = cornerRadius;
    ctx.strokeStyle = '#FF1700';
    ctx.fillStyle = '#FF1700';

    ctx.strokeRect(rectX + (cornerRadius / 2), rectY + (cornerRadius / 2), rectWidth - cornerRadius, rectHeight - cornerRadius);
    ctx.fillRect(rectX + (cornerRadius / 2), rectY + (cornerRadius / 2), rectWidth - cornerRadius, rectHeight - cornerRadius);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to multiply the width of the rectangle with `percentage / 100`. Here is how it would look with your sample code.

```
const rectX = 259;
const rectY = 182;
const rectWidth = 630;
const rectHeight = 38;
const cornerRadius = 20;

const scale = Math.min(1, Math.max(0, percentage / 100));

ctx.lineJoin = 'round';
ctx.lineWidth = cornerRadius;
ctx.strokeStyle = '#FF1700';
ctx.fillStyle = '#FF1700';

ctx.strokeRect(rectX + (cornerRadius / 2), rectY + (cornerRadius / 2), rectWidth - cornerRadius, rectHeight - cornerRadius);
ctx.fillRect(rectX + (cornerRadius / 2), rectY + (cornerRadius / 2), rectWidth * scale - cornerRadius , rectHeight - cornerRadius);
```

When percentage is `100%` scale will be `1` and the width of the rectangle will result in `630`. When percentage is `50%` scale will be `0.5` and the width will be `315` and so on.

Comment: This does not work (I changed percent to 50 for the sake of jsfiddle testing: http://jsfiddle.net/robhawkes/gHCJt/

Comment: However I changed rectWidth to `const rectWidth = 630 * xpPercent / 100;` and it worked! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So from what I understand you have two numbers, starts at at 259 and ends at 630, and 50% would mean the midpoint between these two numbers, 100% would mean 630 and 0% would mean 259, is that correct?

If that's the case, then you need this thing called LERP (linear interpolation),

```
const lerp = (start: number, end: number, percentage: number): number => {
    return (((end - start) * percentage) / 100) + start;
};
```

OR if you want javascript, simply remove the type definitions,

The way it works is by normalizing your start to 0,

Now using this is quite simple: `console.log(lerp(259, 630, 50))`

which returns: `444.5`